# If left / right is laterality what is front / rear?

Tags: vocabulary, semantics, deixis

I want to write something like this:

> Something can be differentiated by laterality [i.e. left - right dimension], by ___  [front - rear dimension], and also by the interaction between laterality and ___ [front-rear dimension].

What would be a proper word for the missing dimension?

---

**Edit note:**

The two sides (left and right) of the body can be differentiated by their laterality. The heart, for example, is a) not symmetrical and b) slightly to the left. A body has laterality because it can be said to have a left and a right side.

Comment: What is [ANOVA]?

Comment: This question can, I'm sure, be answered by experts in a field which uses these terms.

Comment: *Anteriority*, *forwardness*, and several similar words are to be found in dictionaries. (There are a lot of questions here asking what's the name for the scale between two positions, e.g. good and bad, or extravert and introvert, but English tends not to have many words for such scales that aren't named after one side, like goodness/introversion.)

Comment: Have you read papers that make these comparisons? What conventions did they use to describe them?

Comment: What field are you working in? i.e. Where do you see 'laterality' used? It's not a term recognised by most speakers of every day English.

Comment: Somebody should be referring the OP to Fillmore's [Deixis Lectures](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: Is this medicine, art, topology, space navigation or what??

Comment: @Lawrence I googled found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance Read the opening line: *is a collection of statistical models and their associated estimation procedures (such as the "variation" among and between groups) used to analyze the differences among means* and immediately closed the tab. I remain completely and thoroughly in the dark.

Comment: Should "by laterality" be "bilaterally" (having or relating to two sides)?

Comment: Your use of "laterality" does not seem to coincide with the OED: -- 1.  a. The property, condition, or fact of having (distinct) sides, sidedness; right-sidedness or left-sidedness; -- b. Medicine. Asymmetry of the right and left sides of the body (with regard to cutaneous sensitivity, growth, etc.); an instance of this. rare. -- c. Medicine. The condition or fact of being limited or confined to one side of the body or an organ -- 2. Preferred use or superior performance of the left or right hand, eye, etc.

Comment: I recommend simply rewriting the sentence without needing a word that probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore Neuroscience.

Comment: @BryanKrause In some neuroscience paper, when left part is different from right part people say it is "differed by laterality". But I couldn't find any sources how to say difference between anterior part and posterior part.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on biology stack exchange?

Comment: @AndyJunghyunKim That's because the left and right sides of the brain are mirror images. This isn't true for any other direction. In any case, you are using the term laterality wrong which is confusing everyone else here. Can you quote from an actual usage of this rather than your imagined intended use? It's also possible you're reading a text that uses it wrong as well, of course.

Comment: @BryanKrause If I can get this opened, maybe you could do a short frame-challenge answer explaining how *laterality* is actually used? (But if you're not up for that I won't bother!)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think it could be a reasonable question for Psych&Neuro (or possibly Medical Sciences or Biology), but to live any of those places we'd want it to be backed up with some sort of literature reference. That is, we're not going to answer questions there about every person drafting a paper wondering if their wording in English is okay, but if they find this phrasing published somewhere and want it explained or wonder whether it's correct, that seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks. So from the wikipedia article, ANOVA = ANalysis Of VAriation, i.e. working out how different things are. It still seems out of place in the original post, but as it's been edited out, I'm going to leave it be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blausen_0019_AnatomicalDirectionalReferences.png#/media/File:Blausen_0019_AnatomicalDirectionalReferences.png) source on anatomical directional references.

Accordingly, it should be anterior or ventral for the front and posterior or dorsal for the rear direction.

My research says: anteroposterior (antero-posterior) is used to describe both.

Here is [one paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26453593/) that uses the term.

Comment: The OP was looking for a noun. Having said that, surely nobody would recommend "antero-posteriority"?

Comment: It's a noun, like laterality, isn't it?

Comment: A single noun isn't always available and shouldn't necessarily be invented to make a particular construction work. "Antero-posterior dimension" could easily be abbreviated "AP" or "A/P", though, for brevity in text. The whole construction OP suggests seems very questionable, though, and they should really be running this by someone in the field.

Comment: @BryanKrause "A single noun isn't always available and shouldn't necessarily be invented to make a particular construction work."
I am a German native speaker. This is quite an insult :-)
Anyway, I did not invent this word, if even it was invented by the article I was referring to. Especially in subject-specific areas like medicine or science in general, inventing new words is mandatory.

Comment: @SkoboDo I was referring specifically to the "antero-posteriority" creation, though it does seem this one has been used before from a search on Google Scholar - not that I think those people should have used it, either :)

Comment: @BryanKrause Yeah... and that word is in the link I posted. I suggest reading the post you are commenting first.

Comment: @BryanKrause
"not that I think those people should have used it, either :)"
I do not really care. It seems common usage in those scientific fields.

Comment: Well, I did read your answer, which said anteroposterior and antero-posterior - yes, those are normal terms. Anteroposteriorly, too, but that doesn't fit OPs sentence. Anteroposteriority is not common, appearing just a few times. I do *not* see that one in your source.

Comment: @BryanKrause
Are you trollling?:

"I was referring specifically to the "antero-posteriority""

Common pal, I do not really have time for your bs.
Like I said, I do not care about your personal preferences (apparently the academia neither)

Comment: Trolling? Excuse me? I am saying "antero-posteriority"/"anteroposteriority" is not in your source, nor your answer. That would be the noun version of anteroposterior, and I am agreeing with TonyK's comment that I would not recommend it. I don't see why this is so complicated, or why you've accused me of not reading your post.

Comment: It's basically the start of the fucking title...
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26453593/
"Antero-posterior and vertical facial type var..."
wtf?

Comment: I'm talking about the **ity** suffix - the **ity** part that turns it into an abstract noun. I am suggesting not to do that for this word, agreeing with TonyK. "Anteroposterior" is just fine, and very normal terminology, it's the abstract noun form of the word that is not typically used.

Comment: @BryanKrause
I went back the changelog and I could not found the usage of the -ity word...

Comment: @BryanKrause I really do not know what TonyK was talking about. At that time, I even oversaw the -ity suffix in his comment. I have no idea what he was referring too.

Comment: OP requested a noun. "Anteroposterior" is an adjective. If you want to use it as a noun, it needs a suffix to make it one, which makes it "anteroposteriority". TonyK and I are suggesting not to do this. My alternative suggestion was to keep using it as an adjective instead of expecting everything can be nounified, using "anteroposterior" to modify the noun "dimension", since that's what OP is actually using in their model, and abbreviate if "anteroposterior dimension" feels too long.

Comment: A comment about something nobody was talking about, actually. I just presented what I have researched. I never suggested using this word. On the other hand, it is used in papers like you admitted yourself. I do not really see any issue here to discuss besides your personal preferences. 
By the time this answer was open you could easily make your own answer, you didn't. Whatever.